# Why can't copy to other server by scp with openvpn?

Tags: ssh, openvpn, scp

2 nodes:

- node1
- node2

## Node1

```
$ openvpn --genkey --secret /etc/openvpn/server.key
$ ssh-copy-id user@node2:/etc/openvpn/client.key
$ chmod 644 /etc/openvpn/server.key
$ scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa /etc/openvpn/server.key user@node2:/etc/openvpn/client.key
scp: /etc/openvpn/client.key: Permission denied
```

## Node2

```
$ openvpn --genkey --secret /etc/openvpn/server.key
$ ls /etc/openvpn/
client  server  server.key
```

Can't copy server.key from node1 to node2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/openvpn` on node2 should be owned by root.

You are trying to copy a file with `user@node2`, which is not allowed to write in `/etc/openvpn`